# Notepad++ Code Snippet

Tags: ide, editor, notepad++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Notepad++ code snippets manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5147177/notepad-code-snippets-manager)

I realize that Notepad++ is not an IDE but there might be plugins that may emulate this functionality. I know there is a auto complete function in Notepad++ but I am looking for something that can be customized.

I can't remember the exact term, but what I am referring to is:

For example if I write `php` in Notepad++/or some other IDE will replace it with

```
<?php

?>
```

So my question is

What is the terminology for that?

Is there a plugin for Notepad++?

Which Editors/IDE's support this functionality?

Sorry if this been asked before but I can't remember the exact term so I can't search for it.

Comment: @Move-to-SU voter: [Nope.](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions)

Comment: It goes by a few names... I call these code snippets.

Comment: Check out macros too, I use CTRL+E to output `<?php echo  ;?>` and move the caret to just after the "echo". I use CTRL+SHIFT+U to output a base controller class for use with Codeigniter, etc.

Comment: @BoltClock If you can put that as an answer I will accept it and close it.

Comment: @daking963: I'd prefer to keep the duplicate question link, but I've gone ahead to post an answer for completeness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, they're often called code snippets, and you'll find good support for these in the [SnippetPlus](http://sourceforge.net/projects/snippetplus) plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to a page if you are using notepad++ version 5.0.  You may just need to update your version.
http://cybernetnews.com/notepad-50-can-auto-complete-code/

Comment: That's the auto complete. I know about that.

Comment: That's function autocomplete, which has been present in vanilla Notepad++ for quite some time.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows you could use Autohotkey to replace a php with the text you wrote in all windows programs (even your browser). You can of course specify it to only do this in certain programs. This means that you could change IDE in the future without having to learn new auto-completion functionality. This has saved me a ton of keystrokes.