# How to add custom code shortcut in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

Is there a feature or plugin in notepad++ wherein I can type a custom keyword and it will be replaced with a custom code?

For example, I type in:

```
<html>
```

It will turn into:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

<head></head>
<body></body>

</html>
```

Comment: I can't find anything on how to create a custom shortcut as you describe it, but a second-best option could be to create a macro to type the above code and to bind the macro to a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: I will give using macros a shot. Though I saw another text editor (forgot the name) that had that kind of functionality, I thought npp might also have that.

Comment: I have seen this kind of functionality in Eclipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want plugin for making snippets or something like that ? in notepad++ ?
if so there is already such question [Notepad++ code snippet manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5147177/notepad-code-snippets-manager) or [try this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/quicktext/)