# Save a text a reuse it later

Tags: notepad++

**Is there a way in notepad++ to save a text**, like a copyright comment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
    I did write this one day, it's my work
-->
```

**and later (even after closing notepad++), insert it in a file ?**

Somehow, just like a macro, *but* I don't want to start recording a macro, then (carefully) type my text and save that macro.

(may be already answered, but I don't very see what keywords to use)

---

**Edited** (exact scenario)

I have a lot of XML files with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<localization xml:lang="en">
<!-- Some XML nodes -->
</localization>
```

One file for each language, one set of all languages for each project.
In one of these file (`en.xml`), I've wrote a comment about how these files work:

```
<!--
Use loc: namespace for each localization entry.
Nodes without this "loc:" namespace should be containers
and should contain "loc:" nodes or other containers.

@todo    Check every entry for typing mismistakes
@todo    Assign the XSD
-->
```

Now, I want to "save" this text in notepad++ (like a macro, but I don't want to start recording the macro and **retype** the text). Then, later, I open `fr.xml`, and tell notepad++ to paste the saved text at the beginning of the file. Then, I copy nodes from `fr.xml`, paste them somewhere, and mess with Ctrl+C Ctrl+V inside/outside my `fr.xml` (usual stuff). Now, I copy a node from `fr.xml` (like `<loc:foo/>`) and paste it in `de.xml`. And I want to still be able to "paste" the saved text, aka the comment `<!-- Use loc:...`, inside `de.xml` even if I did copy/paste before (so I cannot Ctrl+C the comment because it would erase/be erased by the copy of `<loc:foo/>`).

Currently, the only way I have to do this is:

- start recording a macro
- <del>retype the text</del> I don't want to do this step: I have verbose comments to "record"
- stop recording
- save the macro (with a shortcut).

Retyping the text (some are much longer) while recording the macro is a pain.

**Is there a way to create the macro without retyping the text?
If not, is there a way to "save" a text and insert it later in other files (without `Ctrl+C/Ctrl+V`)?**

Comment: can you please be more specific about your scenario??

Comment: @hariprasad Okay, exact scenario added.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5147177/notepad-code-snippets-manager

Comment: @AdrianHHH Exact, FingerText plugin is what I'm looking for. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FingerText** was the answer.

What I was talking about (save a text "somewhere" in N++ and reuse it later) is called **Code Snippets** (here, it's intended for texts and comments).

FingerText is accessible at https://github.com/erinata/FingerText or through Notepad++ Plugin Manager.

This question was a duplicate of *[Manage code snippets in Notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5147177)*